# How do you get the stock UIToolBar icons?

Tags: ios, ios4, uitoolbar, uitoolbaritem

How do I get the iPhone stock UIToolBar icons?

I need the icons that the standard iphone apps display for for getting the users location and so on.

Answer (score 3):

There are many sources of files online, e.g. [Glyphish Icons](http://glyphish.com/).

If you have photoshop, then you can easily make toolBar icons from Wingdings. Create a canvas with a transparent background, select the text tool, use the Wingdings font to make the pic the size you want. Export to .png and you're done. There are lots of useful icons (houses, mail, etc) from that.